# SQL Primary Key и Foreign Key, объясните принцип

Tags: php, sql

Есть у меня две таблицы: `product_content` и `product_images`. В первой я храню всю текстовую информацию о продукте, в другой я храню адрес для изображений.

Страктура таблиц:

***product_content:***

```
id - primary key
url - varchar
title - varchar
content - text
meta_title - text
meta_description - text
meta_keywords - text
deleted - int (0|1)
```

***product_images***

```
id - primary_key
product_id - int
full_size - text
mini_size - text
deleted -int (0|1)
```

Когда я добавляю продукт, я стоставляю два запроса в БД:

```
`$query_content = "INSERT INTO product_content 
              (url, title, content, meta_title, meta_description, meta_keywords) 
       VALUES (:url, :title, :content, :meta_title, :meta_descritpion, :meta_keywords)";`
```

Потом я получаю последний `id` с запроса `$query_content` и передаю в следующий запрос на вставку изображений. Запрос исполняется в цикле.

```
`$query_image = "INSERT INTO product_images
              (product_id, full_size, mini_size) 
       VALUES (:product_id, :full_size, :mini_size)";`
```

Вопрос: Если я сделаю `product_images` столбец `product_id` - foreign key, то как мне это поможет? Надо ли мне будет получать id продукта, который я вставил в таблицу `product_content`? Я просто совсем не понимаю зачем вообще есть такой индекс как Foreign Key. Могли бы вы объяснить на моём примере. В документацию смотрел, ничего не понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внешний ключ нужен для контроля целостности данных (в MySQL он работает только для движка InnoDB). Нужен он для того, чтобы в таблице product_images не оказалось такого product_id, какого нет в product_content

Comment: То есть, в любом случае мне придется получать последний id записи с таблицы `product_content` при вставке?. Движок я использую только InnoDB, ибо все запросы у меня идут через транзакции. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Да. Но при наличии внешнего ключа СУБД будет более жестко контролировать данные и Вы сможете обнаружить ошибку на более раннем этапе